# Timeframe for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges

Tags: support, publicity-badges

Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges are awarded if the question receives X visits from unique IP addresses with 2, 3 and 4 days, respectively.

Let's say I post a question that does receive many visits. **After a few days** I share a link and it receives 50 unique visitors within 48 hours. Will that count for an Announcer badge?

Or do those visits have to be made from within 48 hours of the question being first posted?

Answer (score 15):

The criteria for these badges [has changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118509), and there is no more timeframe. Any link you share (outside the StackExchange network) to any question or answer (regardless of when the question was asked or when you posted the link) could potentially earn you the badges.

- [Announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/74/announcer): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses
- [Booster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/75/booster): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses
- [Publicist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/76/publicist): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

Comment: Source: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118509/137537

Comment: Thanks, I had some difficulty finding where it was actually posted.

Comment: Sharing direct links to answers now also counts towards these badges. Source: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/158912