# Are Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges given later for answers?

Tags: support, badges, sharing, publicity-badges

I shared [a link to an answer on reddit which also contains my SO id](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2fsdkj/triplequoted_strings_can_replace_pass_keyword/). In 3 days it increased with more than 1400 views which probably could have 1000 unique IPs and surely passed the 25 and 300 unique IPs thresholds, but none of the Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges where given.

According to this Q&A: [Timeframe for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65318/timeframe-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges) and this: [Do shared link to ANSWERS also count for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114607/do-shared-link-to-answers-also-count-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges) the above mentioned badges are given also for answers.

Are Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges given later for answers through a weekly(?) script or the unique IP mechanism failed somehow for this particular link although it contains the id?

Comment: I've received badges for answer links, but have no idea how 'late' the badge was awarded. Take into account that people found the question through *other* means, and that the view count doesn't count unique IP addresses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question gathered around 800 views in its 1 year life when I shared it now it has more than 2200 in this 3 days since I shared the answer on reddit.

Comment: I'd wager the access logs from which the data for the badges is taken are processed periodically in a batch process, I can imagine the data going through a few stages before the badge-awarding process can see the results. If each step is run once a day, that'd add up to a few days. 3 days is a short time, I'd wait another week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Unless you or others shared a link to the *question* elsewhere, you have [received a badge for that answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=1577343) in the end: on 2013-10-24. It seems  Martijn Pieters was right.</del> Sorry, I misread the year: badge was in 2013, reddit in 2014.

As for reasons you were only "attributed" 25 unique visitors instead of your esteemed 1400, perhaps your link had been crossposted on reddit with a different URL.

But I see you got [5 Publicist, 13 Booster and 41 Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577343/eduard-florinescu?tab=badges) by now, so you probably got how it works better than me. ;-) Share what you learnt with a self-answer, maybe?

Comment: It generally works and it didn't work only for that particular post. So I still don't know the answer.

Comment: I think the crosspost is the most sensible answer